# DICOM and OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, visual-c++, dicom

Hai everyone,
             I would like to know whether OpenCV can process DICOM images for 3D reconstruction purpose. Is there any other software that can handle DICOM images other than MATLAB. What about VC++?

Comment: OpenCV cannot do 3D reconstruction, what do you exactly want?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/). It natively handles DICOM images.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is extensible and is written in C++ (I'm not familiar with it, just going from the documentation). So a good start would be an open source C++ DICOM library, there are plenty available.  Here is a list of 17:

[Search I Do Imaging](http://www.idoimaging.com/programs?lang=4&func=512)

Answer (score 1):

C++ and dicom? I would recommend [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk). Efficient, solid, raliable and open source.